# Flutter Provider: How to use a complex state correctly?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am creating an editor (including editing every data field) for next entities:

```
@immutable 
class MainEntity {
   final String name;
   final List<AbstractItem> items;
   // ...
}

abstract class AbstractItem extends Equatable {
   final String id;
   // ...
}

@immutable 
class GroupItemEntity extends AbstractItem  {
   final String name;
   final List<TabEntity> tabs;
   
   @override
   List<Object?> get props => [id, name, tabs];
   // ...
}

@immutable 
class TabEntity {
   final List<ItemEntity> items;

   @override
   List<Object?> get props => [items];
   // ...
}

@immutable 
class ItemEntity extends AbstractItem  {
   final String name;

   @override
   List<Object?> get props => [id, name];
   // ...
}
```

I have a `Provider's` `ChangeNotifier` store:

```
class MainEntityStore extends ChangeNotifier {
   MainEntity _entity = MainEntity.empty();

   String get name => _entity.name;

   void setName(String value) {
     _entity = _entity.copyWith(name: value);
     notifyListeners();
   }

   // ...
}
```

For rendering `ItemEntity` I use a `ItemView` extends `StatelessWidget`, and for `GroupItemEntity` I use a `GroupItemView` extends `StatefulWidget`:

```
class GroupItem extends StatefulWidget implements AbstractView {
   // ...
}

class _GroupItem extends State<GroupItem> {
   int _currentTab = 0;
   // ...
}
```

**Problem:**
When I change a value in `MainEntity`->`GroupEntity`->`TabEntity`->`ItemEntity` the state in `_GroupItem` `_currentTab` resets or `GroupItemView` (or `ItemView` in `GroupItemView`) doesn`t updating.

**Question: How make it correctly?**